# Using 'contains' method in a class array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class like this:

```
public static class TiposDeHistorial
{
    String CODIGO, TIPO;

    public TiposDeHistorial()
    {
    }

    public String getCODIGO()
    {
        return CODIGO;
    }

    public void setCODIGO(String CODIGO)
    {
        this.CODIGO = CODIGO;
    }

    public String getTIPO()
    {
        return TIPO;
    }

    public void setTIPO(String TIPO)
    {
        this.TIPO = TIPO;
    }
}
```

and a list of it:

```
ArrayList<TiposDeHistorial> tiposHistorial;
```

So my question is: can I use `tiposHistorial.contains(...)` to search in a specific array field, `CODIGO` or `TIPO`, for example?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Well, not really, because if I do something like `tiposHistorial.contains("a")` how does the compiler know which one of the class field I'm referring?

Comment: [O/T]: Please make yourself familiar with the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Variable names should be written with lower case letters, or rather *camel case*. Constants on the other hand (`static final`) should be named all upper case.

Comment: Small hint, try to always code in english. That is, use english class names, variable names and so on. In your question, this does not cause any problems, but in more eleborate one, it might, with people not being able to easily understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First of, you do not have an `array` but an `ArrayList`.

The `contains` method on a `List` operates with the `equals` method of it's stored elements (`TiposDeHistorial` in your case). Therefore the answer to your question is no.

Trying something like `tiposHistorial.contains("a")` will not work as there is a type mismatch: your list is of type `TiposDeHistorial` while you try to check for an element of `String`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but you also could give some hints about alternative solutions, like for-each, *commons collections* (`CollectionUtils.find(...)`) or Java 8 streams: `boolean containsCodigo = tiposHistorial.stream().anyMatch(t -> "<find>".equals(t.getCODIGO()));`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can use following code:

```
tiposHistorial.stream()
                .filter(x -> "specific value for CODIGO".equals(x.getCODIGO()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

It will return TiposDeHistorial object in the list containing specific CODIGO value or null otherwise.

As for your question: "contains" method just returns "true" or "false", not an object. Moreover it uses "equals" method of your object, so it will not help if you want to search using fields.

Comment: For **contains** you should use `tiposHistorial.stream().anyMatch(predicate);`

Comment: I know about "anyMatch" but Mazinger wants "to search in a specific array field", i.e. not the fact that element does exist but this element itself.

Comment: As I read it, he wants to test if there's an instance in his list with a certain value in the field 'codigo' or 'tipo'. I don't think he want's the object (yet). Therefore `anyMatch` does excatly this: `boolean containsCodigo = tiposHistorial.stream().anyMatch(t -> "<find>".equals(t.getCODIGO()));`

Answer (score 0):

Contains method will return true only if your object equals with ur list elements objects.
You can try extending equals method and have your own criteria which can work for either CODIGO or TIPO.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        test other = (test) obj;
        if (CODIGO == null) {
            if (other.CODIGO != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!CODIGO.equals(other.CODIGO))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: 1) But that way you have to have an instance of `TiposDeHistorial` with the desired `CODIGO` value to use `.contains(templateTipo)`. You cannot simply test for a 'codigo': `.contains("<codigo>")`
2) You can only implement `equals` for one "identity", you cannot have varying logic: *`CODIGO` **or** `TIPO`*
3) You should also mention, that if you implement `equals()` you also have to implement 'hashCode()'.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already given here are all correct, just if You don't know java streams, and would like to check if the list contains both some CODIGO and TIPO fields, for me the simplest solution would be:

```
    ArrayList<TiposDeHistorial> tiposHistorial = new ArrayList<>();
    //add elements to the list
    String tipo = "TIPO"; // the TIPO value You are looking for in the list
    String codigo = "CODIGO"; // the CODIGO value You are looking for in the list
    boolean containsTipo = false;
    boolean containsCodigo = false;
    for (TiposDeHistorial element: tiposHistorial) {
        if (!containsTipo && element.getTIPO().equals(tipo)) {
            containsTipo = true;
        }
        if (!containsCodigo && element.getCODIGO().equals(codigo) ){
            containsCodigo = true;
        }
        if (containsTipo && containsCodigo)
            break;
    }
```

By editing it just a bit, You may also find which elements of the array contain the values You are looking for, if that will be Your intention

Comment: First of all, thanks everybody for the answers. Jacobek, in fact I did it very similar to your suggestion, with a foreach, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do it in just a simple line of code, like `.contains`

Comment: @Mazinger If you're using *Java 8* you can do it in a single line using Streams API: `boolean contains = tiposHistorial.stream().anyMatch(t -> "<codigo>".equals(t.getCODIGO()) && "<tipo>".equals(t.getTIPO()));`

Comment: OK @Markus, your suggestion it's very interesting, anyway, I was looking for a shorter expression, but yours is very good as well. Thanks!